# prometheus-postgres-exporter add metrics to bitnami/kube-prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator, helm3

I have a cluster deployed with:
https://bitnami.com/stack/prometheus-operator/helm
and
https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter

How to properly add own metrics to the prometheus-operator list of metrics that postgres_exporter exports ?

I tried it that way:

```
helm upgrade kube-prometheus bitnami/kube-prometheus \
    --set prometheus.additionalScrapeConfigs.enabled=true \
    --set prometheus.additionalScrapeConfigs.type=internal \
    --set prometheus.additionalScrapeConfigs.internal.jobList=
      - job_name: 'prometheus-postgres-exporter' 
        static_configs:
          - targets: ['prometheus-postgres-exporter.default:80']
```

but it doesn't work ('job_name:' are not added to the Prometheus Configuration).

Comment: How are you installing the postgres_exporter?

Comment: helm install prometheus-postgres-exporter prometheus-community/prometheus-postgres-exporter

Answer (score 3):

Use [ServiceMonitors](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-monitoring-prometheus-operator-part3/) if using Prometheus Operator.

Configure the following block under the values.yaml in the postgres-exporter helm chart.This allows Prometheus Operator to read and configure jobs automatically.

```
serviceMonitor:
  # When set true then use a ServiceMonitor to configure scraping
  enabled: true
  # Set the namespace the ServiceMonitor should be deployed
  namespace: <namespace where prometheus operator is deployed.>
  # Set how frequently Prometheus should scrape
  interval: 30s
  # Set path to cloudwatch-exporter telemtery-path
  telemetryPath: /metrics
  # Set labels for the ServiceMonitor, use this to define your scrape label for Prometheus Operator
  # labels:
  # Set timeout for scrape
  # timeout: 10s
  # Set of labels to transfer from the Kubernetes Service onto the target
  # targetLabels: []
  # MetricRelabelConfigs to apply to samples before ingestion
  # metricRelabelings: []
```

Comment: I added these parameters to the Prometheus-Postgres-Exporter configuration (they are successfully displayed after the command "helm get values prometheus-postgres-exporter"), but the new targets or Service Discovery in Prometheus did not appear.
I also rebooted Prometheus Operator and did not change.
Is there a good manual, where this task is implemented and why not working?

Comment: Check this post.Dont create the objects as in your case they are already available. Also go through the comments in the answer. https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/14097/enable-ingress-nginx-prometheus-monitoring-without-helm/14098#14098